# Improve Edit Community ♦/my paired timestamps off by a second

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

In [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8213688) I just Improved, the timestamp for my edit is about a second later than Community ♦'s. Odd. This is not in itself particularly serious, but it makes me worry a bit about the atomicity of the review action.

(It was especially noticeable the first minute, but hovering still reveals the difference.)

Comment: When you improved the edit you effectively trigger the community user so it can "push" through an immediate change. *Then* you get acknowledgement for the edit after... so might be the same second, but not overly surprising if you did it at 0.9 of a second you'd fall into the next second...